# Можно-ли вставить iframe в HTML-письмо?

Tags: html, email

Можно-ли вставить iframe в HTML-письмо?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ: да, можно.

Скорее всего вас заинтересует, в каких почтовых клиентах `iframe` внутри html-письма будет корректно отображаться: [Do iframes work in email?](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3219/do-iframes-work-in-email/)